# How to Find Jerk from Discrete Velocity Data?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, discrete, jerk

I have measured the velocity of an object at discrete intervals. I want to find the corresponding acceleration and jerk of the object. How do I do this with discrete values rather than continuous variables?

I think acceleration is simply a = (V2-V1)/(t2-t1), but what times do I use for the jerk equation?

If I were to plot these values, what times would I plot acceleration and jerk against? i.e. does a1 pair with t1 or t2? Or do I plot a1 over the interval between t1 and t2?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since what you calculated here is not instantaneous acceleration but rather average acceleration, you can't determine the average jerk.
You can only estimate a value for average jerk.
And because it is only an estimation you can consider the average accelerations you obtained between $t_1$ and $t_2$ to be instantaneous acceleration at $(t_1+t_2)/2$ just for the sake of finding an estimate.
Note: This won't give you the exact value of jerk but only an estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) over measured data is tricky. It will typically result in very noisy results. For only a small sample of points, it is better to start with the *underlying mathematical model* and use the points to fine-tune the model parameters.

Then you can use the mathematical model to estimate higher-order derivatives such as jerk.

If you had more points, depending on the amount of noise present, you would a) smooth the data using an exponential kernel and b) fit cubic-splines around the data.

The cubic spline will provide a linear relationship between intervals for the 2nd derivative (jerk in this case).

But I digress. To get jerk at point $i$ using finite differences, then do

$$ j_i = \frac{v_{i-1}-2\,v_i+v_{i+1}}{h^2} $$ with $h$ beign the time interval. This is a result of the finite difference of the two accelerations at half intervals before and after

$$ \begin{aligned} 
a_{i-\tfrac{1}{2}} & = \frac{v_i - v_{i-1}}{h} & a_{i+\tfrac{1}{2}} & = \frac{v_{i+1} - v_{i}}{h}
\end{aligned}$$

and then

$$ j_i \frac{ a_{i+\tfrac{1}{2}} - a_{i-\tfrac{1}{2}} }{h} $$

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to estimate the third derivative [numerically](http://isdl.cau.ac.kr/education.data/numerical.analysis/Lecture17.pdf), using unevenly distributed data points. I suggest you use Lagrange interpolation or assume averaged times; see the end of this answer if you are impatient.

[For regular intervals one can relatively easily derive a formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301769/approximation-formula-for-third-derivative-is-my-approach-right) from the Taylor expansion. There a lots of [finite difference schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), but most hinge on the intervals being regular.

For irregular data one can fit a curve to the points and take the derivative of the curve at the desired time. For example, you could use a [Lagrange interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to fit three data points $(t_1,v_1),(t_2,v_2),(t_3,v_3)$ and calculate the jerk from that for points in in the interior. Note that you will get two possible values depending on whether you use point 1,2,3 or 2,3,4. Calculating derivatives of [Lagrange polynomials is tedious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Derivatives) (you need the second derivative) but can of course be automated. Plus, there is risk that the interpolating polynomial bends and misbehaves - numerical differentiation tends to increase errors.

However, you can use other forms of fit that doesn't strictly go through the points but use data further out and some regularization such as [splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) to make things more robust if you know your data is fairly continuous. I suspect professionals would use Chebyshev approximations.

See also [this paper for lots and lots of references](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704006454) to different methods. [Fornberg's method](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/home.html) seem to be popular and robust. Another approach is described in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5d46/ea0f6cae94db6214789e2981429b78900c56.pdf) that uses only $n$ points leading up to a given moment in time to estimate derivatives.

However, at this point it is useful to lean back in your chair and consider: what are you planning to use the result for? What level of error is acceptable? Do you need strong bounds on it (that is something that interests the numerical analysis people a lot)? Or is this just to get a sense of the magnitude of the jerk? Does it truly matter to evaluate it at particular points in time, or could you interpolate between the values?

If I really needed the jerk at time $t$ I would bite the bullet and use the Lagrange interpolation method - a fair bit of algebra, but since you have the velocity the fitting polynomial is just quadratic and hence not too numerically unstable. The fact that this method will give intervals where estimates are different depending on which data points are used is just a fact of life: maybe one can take the average, or even interpolate.

If I only needed a magnitude estimate I would use your formula. It is a repeated center difference estimate, so the relevant times in the second step are the averages: $(t_1+t_2)/2$ and $(t_3+t_4)/2$.

**Addendum**: thinking a bit more, one doesn't need to do fancy Lagrange interpolation. If you have three points $(t_1,v_1),(t_2,v_2),(t_3,v_3)$ you can fit a parabola $v(t)=at^2+bt+c$ to them and get the jerk $v''(t)=2a$. The magical thing is that this is constant for each parabola!

Even better, if you take the three equations you get to fit the points to the parabola you get the linear system $$\left[\begin{matrix}
t_1^2 & t_1 & 1\\
t_2^2 & t_2 & 1\\
t_3^2 & t_3 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{matrix}\right]
$$
that you can solve using Gauss elimination, giving
$$a = \frac{(v_3-v_1)(t_2-t_1) - (v_2-v_1)(t_3-t_1)}{(t_3^2-t_1^2)(t_2-t_1) - (t_2^2-t_1^2)(t_3-t_1)}.$$
The jerk is twice this.

Note that I have not done any careful numerical stability checking here like a professional numerics guy would have done. But since you are likely not close to the limits of computer numeric precision this is likely not a problem.  It will also be behaving badly when the denominator $\approx 0$, and this might happen if there is noise in the data: add some sanity checking to the code.

[image: Plot of jerk estimates for four points]

So for your data, you may want to estimate the jerk in the interval $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ as the mean of the jerk given by the above from data at $t_{i-1},t_i,t_{i+1}$ and $t_{i},t_{i+1},t_{i+2}$

Comment: Another thing: real data is noisy, and for example phone accelerometers sample rapidly but noisily. That means that just using raw velocity data for the estimation will produce nonsense: it has to be denoised. But that also strongly affects the jerk estimate! Some care is needed. For example, you may want to run a median filter over every three data points and then use those results to estimate the jerk at a lower rate. I also notice that some apps save points with the same claimed time, further emphasizing the need for data cleaning or least-mean-square curve fitting. Real world data, ugh!